# Xcodeでビルド時にCFBundleExecutableのエラーが発生する

Tags: swift, xcode

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんが、xcodeでbuildする際に
画面のようなエラーが発生するようになってしまいました。
[image: エラー画面]
info.plistにExecutable fileの項目はもともと設定していなかったと思うのですが、
これは必要なんでしょうか？
また、設定するとして、値は何をいれたらいいんでしょうか？

勉強不足で申し訳ありませんが、よければ教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CFBundleExecutable`（`Executable file`）の値が無いか、間違っているというエラーメッセージですね。

`CFBundleExecutable`はビルドされたアプリケーション自体のファイル名を指すもので、必要ですし、初期状態（Xcodeプロジェクトを作っただけの状態）で最初から自動的に追加されているものです。

なのでもともと設定していなかったというのは勘違いか、間違って消してしまったものと思われます。

下記はプロジェクトを新しく作った場合の初期状態のInfo.plistのキャプチャです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力] [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

初期状態では`EXECUTABLE_NAME`というビルド変数を参照するようになっています。たいていはこれで問題ないので（漢字などを含むプロジェクト名を作ったりしていなければ）このように戻せばエラーは直ると思います。

ちなみに`EXECUTABLE_NAME`というビルド変数は、PRODUCT_NAME, EXECUTABLE_PREFIX, EXECUTABLE_SUFFIXの３つの変数から組み立てられる値です。

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW71

Comment: ありがとうございます！
無事に解決しました
新しくプロジェクトを作っても見たんですが、ちょっと勘違いしてたみたいです。
本当に助かりました